# Add tf.image.decode_jpeg to Keras created graph

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to try to use Keras Sequential model in order to train a convnet on an image classification problem. 
My training set is 18K images 455x255 which is probably too big to fit into memory and so I would like to use some kind of a batch pipeline.

In my original tensorflow implementation I have this code which is simlar to the [MNIST tensorflow example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded_var.py)

How can I feed this pipeline into the Sequential model, to create something like the Keras [cifa10_cnn example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py)

```
with tf.name_scope('input'):
  # Input data
  images_initializer = tf.placeholder(
    dtype=tf.string,
    shape=[len_all_filepaths])
  labels_initializer = tf.placeholder(
    dtype=tf.int32,
    shape=[len_all_filepaths])
  input_images = tf.Variable(
    images_initializer, trainable=False, collections=[])
  input_labels = tf.Variable(
    labels_initializer, trainable=False, collections=[])

  image, label = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
    [input_images, input_labels], num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)

  # process path and string tensor into an image and a label
  file_contents = tf.read_file(image)
  image_contents  = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents, channels=NUM_CHANNELS)
  image_contents.set_shape([None, None, NUM_CHANNELS])

  # Rotate if necessary
  rotated_image_contents, = tf.py_func(rotate, [image_contents], [tf.uint8])
  rotated_image_contents.set_shape([IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, NUM_CHANNELS])
  rotated_image_contents = tf.image.per_image_whitening(rotated_image_contents)

  images, labels = tf.train.batch(
    [rotated_image_contents, label],
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
    num_threads=16,
    capacity=3 * FLAGS.batch_size
  )


# Build a Graph that computes predictions from the inference model.
logits = model.inference(images, len(correct_labels))

# Add to the Graph the Ops for loss calculation.
loss = model.loss(logits, labels)

# Add to the Graph the Ops that calculate and apply gradients.
train_op = model.training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ImageDataGenerator from Keras already does batching for you. I don't understand why the Keras datagen.fit() with a specified batch size and a standard generator doesn't work for your use case.

Comment: Well, if I understand things correctly, the Keras batch generator is just a python generator which doesn't do multithreading for performance. Also it doesn't allow me to add custom handling like py_func (for example rotating portrait images into landscape). Also, if I want to do zca_whitening/center, I need to do generator.fit() before...

Comment: The solution here is to use the images/labels you get from tf.train.batch(), wrap them in keras.layers.Input(), and pass the result to your other keras layers.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I think I figured out how to do this with the X input, but I'm not sure how to do the same with the label data which is batched....